# Mouseleave does not working properly on option select

Tags: jquery, mouseleave

I have a option select follows

```
<select class="myselect">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

Jquery for mouseleave

```
$('.myselect').live('mouseleave',function(){
    alert('Sample');
});
```

But i can't select the values of dropdown

Comment: what is your requirement

Comment: What motto does it have with mouseleave? What do you want with it now?

Comment: I want to select the values from the option select but it have a mouse over event so i can't select the values from option select

Comment: What version of jquery are you using ?

Comment: Mouse leave works, live() not `As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().`